# Eclipse Android imports is not recognized

Tags: android

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
```

Eclipse launched from adt-bundle-windows-x86_64 is not able to see following imports. Windows->Preferences->Androind points to valid SDK location.

I launched SDK manager and installed all components offer by SDK manager by default. However it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project > Properties > Android and choose a build target. Your project at the moment has no build target, and so Eclipse does not know what `android.jar` file to use to resolve your imports.

Comment: Looks like I imported project as regular Java project. Should import as Andoind project instead. That's why I had not got Android menu